# ejabberd chat users across domain

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

We are using ejabberd and on that,
I have created two virtual host(domain) say
example.com
example.net

and each domain has one user say
user1 in example.com
user2 in example.net

I have two questions :

1. I want user1 shall able to send IQ and message user 2 (same vice-versa)
2. How can i restrict  user 2 shall receive only message,IQ only from user1 ?

Criteria:
Number of users in each domain can be in thousands but there is one to one associate exists between this two domain  (say user1@example.com -> user2@example.net,  like that user3@example.com ->user4@example.net

can you suggest the best way to achieve this ? Sorry i am new to XMPP, so asking this basic question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install mod_filter from ejabberd-contrib git repository, probably you can filter that. But it would require adding a line to the configuration file for each pair of userX-userY, so I guess it isn't practical...

Comment: Thank you.  Is this mod filter (privacy list) scalable  ( i mean thousands of users) and can add/remove entries dynamically (via REST APIs) ?   or is it possible with Roster ?  For example, create Roster for user1 and user2. Set to contact only within roster ?

Comment: I think not possible.